# How can I manually define column types in OLEDB/JET DataTable?

Tags: vb.net, oledb, jet

I am importing data from an Excel spreadsheet to a VB.NET `DataTable`.  This Excel spreadsheet has a lot of garbage data in the first 18 rows, including a lot of empty cells.  I ultimately remove these rows in post-processing, but I need to access the Excel file as is, without modifying it by hand at all.

I realize that setting `IMEX=1` instructs the Jet engine to assume all columns are text.  However, I have an issue with setting it to another value (explained more below).  So, the default Jet engine column type scan wouldn't work particularly well.

I'd like to either:

1. Manually define column types before the import
2. Force Excel to scan many more rows (I believe the default is 8) to determine the column type

However, I do have an issue with idea #2.  I do not have administrative rights to open `regedit.exe`, so I can't modify the registry using that method.  I did circumvent this before by importing a key somehow, but I can't remember how I did it.  So #1 would be an ideal solution, unless someone can help me carry out idea #2.

Is this possible?  Currently, I'm using the following method:

```
If _
    SetDBConnect( _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & filepath & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""", True) Then

    dtSchema = _dh.GetOleDbSchemaTable()

    If _dh.Errors <> "" Then
       Throw New Exception("::LoadFileToBuffer.GetOleDbSchemaTable::" & _dh.Errors())
    End If

    For Each sheetRow In dtSchema.Rows
       If sheetRow("TABLE_NAME").ToString() = "TOTAL_DOLLARS$" Then
          totalDollars = sheetRow("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
        ElseIf sheetRow("TABLE_NAME").ToString() = "TOTAL_UNITS$" Then
          totalUnits = sheetRow("TABLE_NAME").ToString()
       End If
    Next

    'Get total dollars table
     sql.Append("SELECT * FROM [" & totalDollars & "]")
     dtDollars = _dh.GetTable(sql.ToString())
End If
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to say:

```
 sql.Append("SELECT * FROM [" & totalDollars & "$A18:X95]")
```

Where totalDollars  is a sheet name and x95 is the last valid row. You will not be able to include headers unless they are available at row 18.

Comment: Wow.  This makes it so much simpler!  Thanks.  Is there any way to SELECT FROM sheetName $A18 to the last row with data in the first column besides hard-coding the cell name?

Comment: Not really, but you should be able to get the last row / column from your original query of the full sheet or from interop. You can then use it to build the string: `& "$A18:X" & last & "]"` AFAIR, you can refer to a very high row/column and only the used rows / columns will be read.